# Persistent Mechanical Feedback

Tags: led, magnetics, mechanical, latching, electro-mechanical

I am looking for a device (preferably in a small form factor) that can provide feedback for the user even after the power has been removed from the PCB (No, I don't want a battery powered solution.). (This device would need to be soldered onto the PCB.)

Basically, I am trying to replace a status feedback LED with something that continues to give feedback (holds its state) even after the PCB is no longer powered.
So, for example, I have a board with a bipolar LED: red for error, green for OK. I want something, that can **visually** indicate that an error has occurred (eg. over voltage) even after the PCB is no longer connected to the power supply and thus the LED isn't able to stay on any longer to indicate the error by being red.

I have some bistable (latching) mechanical solution in mind. Like a bistable (latching) relay with a state feedback, just without the power coil.

So basically I am looking for a latching mechanical LED... :D

Are there such feedback components on the market?
Do you know what they are called, how I can search for them?
Do you know some specific device mabey to get me started in my search?

Comment: Wouldn't the lack of illumination of any LED be sufficient?

Comment: A tiny stepper motor?

Comment: @Andyaka What I understand, he want the last indication to hold

Comment: @Andyaka A lack of illumination just means that the board is not powered. I need something that indicates that the board needs attention before reuse, even after the power has been removed (because for example there was an over voltage event that could have messed the electronics up).

Comment: A flip disc maybe?

Comment: @Oldfart  That would be way to much of a complication, then I would need a driver, a driver logic, etc. Are there latching stepper motors at all or they could be just turned after the loss of power?

Comment: @Hearth Yes, something exactly like that, just much smaller. Something that fits on a PCB.

Comment: @Cerike um, these most definitely fit on a PCB. Have you actually clicked [through to their components](https://flipdots.com/en/products-services/status-indicators/)?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Yes, of course everything fits on a big enough PCB. What I meant is that they are humongous. I need something which is just marginally bigger than a through hole LED. To be more precise, the lateral dimensions can be a relatively big, but it really shouldn't be 11mm tall.

Comment: @Cerike It's about twice the size of a standard LED, and a large, easy-to-spot indicator is not a bad thing.

Comment: @Cerike if you have specific size requirements, please do explicitly state them in your question – it's hard to read your mind, you know ;)

Answer (score 1):

How about blowing a fuse.  Put a fuse on the incoming power.  When there's an error then short the fuse with a transistor.  The fuse blows and the board is dead.  If someone tries to use the board after it won't work and they'll have to start investigating.

Answer (score 1):

If [flip dots](https://flipdots.com/en/products-services/status-indicators/) don't suit your needs, try one of the following:

A remote-reset switch, which can be flipped into the off position by an electrical signal and must be manually reset. [Here's one](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/omron-electronics-inc-emc-div/A8GS-S1205/SW1532-ND/4248836).

For a bit less money, you could get a small circuit breaker, one that you can trip on command with a pulse of current. Something like one of [these](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/schurter-inc/4435-0595/486-6634-ND/2769310), maybe.

Answer (score 0):

There are Bi-Stable displays, both electro-mechanical (A disc with red and green painted on it that can change state) and E-ink types.
Mechanical flip dots: [example](https://flipdots.com/en/home/)